# What can I conclude about the distribution of wrong phone numbers?

Tags: distributions, bayesian, conditional-probability

Let's say I have a list of 100 phone numbers. I call them all. Nobody picks up for 70. I get someone on the line for 30. Of those, 10 are wrong numbers. What can I conclude about the distribution of wrong numbers in the full list of 100 numbers?

Comment: Welcome to our site.  Could you explain what a "wrong number" means?  Regardless, you provide little evidence to justify any assumptions that the 70 non-answerers have much in common with the answerers: it looks like you have a large *survey non-response rate* but have provided no information that would help understand or analyze it.  Advice on this topic can be found by searching our site for keywords that include "missing."

Comment: My list contains cell phone numbers and the name of the person who is supposed to be associated with that cell phone number. A wrong number is when somebody answers the phone but they are not the person that I have on my list. Ascforvhow comparable the groups are, I don't actually know. Can we assume for simplicity that the 100 people are a random draw from a larger population?

Comment: If you like--but that doesn't help us get any closer to an answer.  The problem is that one can imagine many reasons why the rate of wrong numbers differs between answerers and non-answerers.  That makes it impossible to conclude anything about the 70 where nobody picked up.  You either need to track some of them down or else make some (very) strong assumptions (which could be justified for some populations and some procedures for calling, I imagine).

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y$ be wrong numbers in the full list of 100 numbers.

Then $Y = 10 + Z$, and $Z$ follows binomial distribution with number of trials n = 70 and probability ($\pi$) of wrong number among "nobody picks up", $ Z$ ~Bin$(70,\pi)$

The range of $Y$ is from 10 to 80.

If you want to estimate the probability of wrong number among "nobody picks up", another study/trial is needed.